# Upload File on local server through Webview on Android Studio

Tags: android, server, webview, upload

i manage in english, so i'll try to explain my self easily.
I made a small responsive website locally with PHP, it works very well, I used webviews to test my site on mobile, and it works well too. But I can't import an image with my webview, the button doesn't even react. However, when I access the local server via my IP address, it works fine on the phone and I even import images directly from the phone. attached my src code

```
  mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

        mywebView.loadUrl("http://172.16.3.22/Server/index.html");
```

my Manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```